# What is this insect and how to kill it?

Tags: insect

What is the name of insect in linked photo and how we can kill it in easy way

[image]

Comment: Perhaps better on Biology.

Comment: where are you located, country/state?

Comment: In future, including some sort of scale on the photo will be very helpful.

Comment: M living in Pakistan

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. This isn't really on-topic here, but let's see if you get any useful answers. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the [Pyrrharctia Isabella](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyrrharctia_isabella), or woollybear. [Thuricide](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Southern-Ag-8-oz-Thuricide-BT-Caterpillar-Control-Concentrate-100520028/100599150)<sup>1</sup> is labelled as a catepillar control pesticide.

<sub>1 Home Depot link, no endorsement as I have never used this myself</sub>

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer (and my complements on the sub/sup HTML); keep 'em coming.